# How to detect the New li automatically created by ol lists in an editable div?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I want to detect the new li only created by ol in a div.I want to auto inrease the id of the new li.

**Note:** The new li are being created by ol list but not by onclick event.

```
<div id="txtarea" contenteditable="true">Some text</div>

    var counter = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
            var html = "<div class='steps ' style='background-color: #d3d3d3 !important'><ol ><li class='personid'  id='"+  counter++   +"' style='border: solid white 1px'><a href='url-here' >Link Text </a></li></ol><div>";

    $("#txtarea").html(html);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following code here i am creating only 10 li you have to also increase if you want.

Some text

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 0;
    var html = "<div class='steps ' style='background-color: #d3d3d3 !important'><ol >";
    var data = "";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        while (counter < 10) {
            data = data + "<li class='personid'  id='" + counter + "' style='border: solid white 1px'><a href='url-here' >Link Text </a></li>";
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        html = html + data + "</ol><div>";

        $("#txtarea").html(html);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your help.You did not get my question.I only want to dtetect the li created by ol and not by any manual(onclick or while loop) function